# Add seconds to a given date in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, time, date

I have a complete date plus hours and minutes. I would like to add a number of seconds and display the result as a date "day.month.year hour:minute".

"date" doesn't seem to be able to add seconds to a given date.

Comment: BASH so I assumed command line ;)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts

Answer (score 16):

In fact, the GNU `date` command (which is the standard implementation in Ubuntu) can add date offsets directly - for example to add 3662 seconds (1hr, 1min, 2sec) to a given date

```
$ date '+%d.%b.%Y %T' --date="2012-06-13 09:16:16 EDT + 3662 seconds"
13.Jun.2012 10:17:18
```

However, some care is required with timezones and daylight savings - a safer option is probably to convert the original time into seconds since the start of the epoch, and add the desired offset to that before converting back to the desired format, e.g.

```
$ secs=$(date +%s --date="2012-06-13 09:16:16")
$ date '+%d.%b.%Y %T' --date="@$((secs + 3662))"
13.Jun.2012 10:17:18
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also increment the current date easily with:

```
date --date="+1 seconds" '+%Y-%m-%d %T'
```

`man date` says this is documented in `info date`, but I don't feel like reading `info` manuals now to quote it :-)

Tested in Ubuntu 18.04, `date` from Coreutils 8.28.

Comment: `+1 sec` works too

Comment: Stick to the original question, adding date to the given date not to the current date.

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
$ date +%x.%H:%M:%S:%N
01/21/2014_16:02:07:422856522
```

It shows a US styled data for me but see [man date](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) for more refinement. The 2 interesting options:

```
%N     nanoseconds (000000000..999999999)
%S     second (00..60)
```

And if you want to use the standard year, month, day format:

```
$ date +%Y.%m.%d_%H:%M:%S:%N
2014.07.21_16:07:52:641771706
```

Comment: Why do you need nanoseconds..?

Comment: because I can @wilf He says: can not add seconds. I say: yes and even nanoseconds :+)

Comment: This is not an answer. The question was adding some amount of seconds to date and then represent in a format which doesn't even have seconds/nanosecods in mind

Comment: You were using %M both for months and for minutes. It should be %m (lowercase) for month. Edited answer.